# ¿como guardar cambios de un entry con append?

Tags: python, tkinter

soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y para practicar me propuse hacer mi propio programa basándome en broma con mi pareja,básicamente suele poner muchas excusas tontas por lo que decidí crear un archivo .py en el cual con una lista de sujetos y una de acciones las mezcle aleatoriamente creando una excusa rara en un warning.
hasta ahí bien,mi problema ahora es que me gustaría que con un Entry poder añadir a la listas mas sujetos y acciones de manera permanente,conozco el método append pero solo guarda lo añadido hasta reinicio el programa.
adjunto el código para que puedan revisarlo.
agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda y estoy abierto a escuchar cualquier consejo para mejorar.
muchas gracias y buen día.

```
import random
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

#parametros tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Excusaleria,creacion original de Ericcs")

#opciones a elegir
sujeto = ["una foca","un perro","faro","un alien","un aleman furioso","un pedo viviente"]
accion = [" se comio mis deberes"," se meo en la cama"," me mordio el pelo"," me sondeo"," me puso un bigote por cejas"," se cago en mis pantalones"]

#mezcla y output
def aleat():
    Rsujeto = random.choice(sujeto)
    Raccion = random.choice(accion)
    tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="excusa", message="esque..." + Rsujeto + Raccion)

boton = tkinter.Button(window, text="pulsame", command=aleat, width=40, height=20)
boton.pack()

#agregar contenido
def new():
    agr_suj = new_suj.get()
    sujeto.append(agr_suj)


new_suj = tkinter.Entry(window)
new_suj.pack()

añadir = tkinter.Button(window, text="añadir", command=new)
añadir.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el metodo append, podrás guardar los datos en la lista hasta que acabe el programa, pero si quieres que se guarde de manera permanente, te sugiero guardar los sujetos y las acciones en archivos llamados 'sujetos' y 'acciones'.

```
def guardar_accion(accion:str):
    # Abrimos el archivo con el modo append para agregar datos:
    with open('acciones.txt', 'a') as file:
        # Agregamos un salto de linea '\n' para separar los datos agregados:
        file.write(accion + '\n')

def guardar_sujeto(sujeto:str):
    with open('sujetos.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(sujeto + '\n')
```

Y si quieres recuperar los datos y colocarlos en una lista, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
# Leemos el archivo y lo convertimos en una lista:
sujetos = open('sujetos.txt', 'r').read().split()
sujetos = [sujeto.strip() for sujeto in sujetos]
```

Puedes hacer lo mismo con las acciones.

Comment: ,muchas gracias por responder,ahora mi problema es que al generar me salen palabras sueltas en vez de las uniones(es decir en vez de el perro sale o el o perro) y también que a la hora de de querer guardar en el txt me sale un error `guardar_sujeto() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sujeto'`.,probé con un contenedor con un .get en el entry pero nada,agradecería cualquier consejo,muchas gracias y buen día.

Comment: Hola, en la respuesta anterior tuve un pequeño error, al leer los archivos para guardar los sujetos/acciones en listas, use el metodo "split()", debes ponerle un argumento, quedaría así: ".split('\n')". Y el otro error "missing 1 required positional argument", es porque al llamar a la función debes poner el sujeto entre los parentesis, por ejemplo: "guardar_sujeto(new_suj.get())", así logras obtener el texto del entry, y lo pones como argumento en la función "guardar_sujeto()". Saludos